# Stroustrup swan book Vector Problem

Tags: c++, vector

I'm using Stroustrup's swan book. I have run into a problem getting output from a
vector. I followed the text example from sec. 4.6.3 on page 121. I
managed to get the source compiled and am able to execute it. After
typing in a list of whitespace separated words, the program hangs and
does not list the elements of the vector as it should. I realize not
every element will be outputted if it is repeated, but i receive no
output at all. I have compiled and run this using the g++ 4.3.2
compiler on Linux and using the Visual C++ express 2008 compiler on
windows. Both produce the same result. Thank you for taking time to
read this. Here is my source:

```
#include "Supporting_files/std_lib_facilities.h"

    int main()
            {
        vector<string> words;
        string temp;
        cout << "Enter a list of words: ";
        while(cin>>temp)
            words.push_back(temp);
            cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << endl;
            sort(words.begin(),words.end());
            for(int i=0;i<words.size();++i)
                if(i==0||words[i-1]!=words[i])
                    cout << words[i] << "\n";
            }
```

Comment: I met Stroustrup... </pointless-comment>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

while(cin>>temp) only ends when it hits an end of file. Use control-D to send an end of file into the terminal.